# Can allah prevent this ?

Tags: dua

Okay so my friend  is worried that her webcam was hacked all this time , can she make dua and pray to allah to make sure it wasn't ?

Comment: If it was hacked then nothing can be done about it. She can make dua that no ill effect comes her way due to that

Answer (score 2):

Allah is the one who covers a secret and who uncovers it.
If your friend did not intend any evil surely Allah is her protector (even otherwise).
Allah is all knowing and watching.
May Allah protect the haya of the women and give us all correct understanding of the deen.